# How can apply_filters be used to create a filter hook in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, hook

Wordpress [documentation about apply_filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) mentions:

> It is possible to **create new filter hooks** by simply calling this function, specifying the name of the new hook using the $hook_name parameter.

Ok, I want to create a filter hook called `the_content2`, so I do what the docs suggest:

```
$custom_hook = apply_filters("the_content2", the_content());
```

Now I assume `the_content2` hook is created and is similar to `the_content`. So on a single post page I should be able to use `the_content2` hook like `the_content2`:

`the_content2()`

This throws error, function is not defined. I am beginner in wordpress, can someone please explain comprehensively how `apply_filters` can be used to create your own filters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hooks (actions and filters) have two main components, the part that declares the hook, and the callbacks that implement the hook.

A very simple example is:

```php
$name = "Chris";
$name = apply_filters("change_name", $name);
echo $name;
```

If no one registers a callback, then `Chris` will be outputted. However, if someone writes this:

```php
add_filter(
    "change_name",
    function($name){ return "Steve";}
);
```

Then `Steve` will be outputted.

At no point, however, will a new *function* called `change_name()` be created.

As it relates to hooks, I would generally steer you away from thinking about a hook "being created", and instead think about it as "being called". A function always exists, but hooks are only used if they are actually called.

To your main issue as it relates to `the_content()`, I would determine what you want to do with that. If you want to transform the result of that function for all instances, a hook is probably a good idea. However, if you just want to use it differently sometimes, a custom function (without a hook) that calls the original, does something and returns it might be more appropriate.

**EDIT**

Below is a mock of how the hook system works. I've simplified it a bunch, but it should give you a gist of how it works.

```php
function add_filter($name, $callback) {
    global $filters;
    $filters[$name][] = $callback;
}

function apply_filters($name, $value) {
    global $filters;
    if(array_key_exists($name, $filters)) {
        foreach($filters[$name] as $callback) {
            $value = $callback($value);
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

I can't stress this enough, no one is really *declaring* or *registering* things. At most, an array key is added with a name when the `add_filter`/`add_action` is used. Then, *if* someone calls the `apply_filters`/`do_action` then the key is looked up, and if it exists, the callbacks are run.

So `add_filter`/`add_action` has to happen first. It is "I'm interested in XYZ if it actually happens". There's many cases where it might not happen, but if it does, then the callback will fire.

The `apply_filters` can't/shouldn't throw an error if no one registered a callback, because that is totally a valid case. I often write code that is extensible for future callers but you'll notice that if no one adds a filter, the initial value is returned.

Comment: If I run `add_filter(
    "change_name",
    function($name){ return "Steve";}
);` without ever declaring the hook with `$name = apply_filters("change_name", $name);`, why then doesn't wordpress throw error _hook change_name undefined_? what is the other way of declaring a hook? how does wordpress declare `the_content` hook? what's even the point of "_`apply_filter` can declare a hook_", if the hook can only run by `apply_filters` itself?

Comment: I think the documentation is incorrect. Let's say `change_name` was never declared. Now do:

`add_filter(
    "change_name",
    function($name){ return $name."Steve";}
);
$name = apply_filters("change_name", "rome");
echo $name;`

The first call to `apply_filters` should not execute the filter, it should just declare the filter. But since, we don't see this behaviour, I think in wordpress, there's no such thing as creating/declaring a filter. Any filter hook can be executed without ever being created.

Comment: I've made some edits above to hopefully explain what's going on. If you dive into the real code you'll see they have objects, priorities and variadic parameters, but for the sake of argument I've simplified things to give you a gist of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks mate, it makes more sense now. WordPress documentation is using really bad lingo there. I saw the code of `the_content()` and `the_title()`, they are just doing `apply_filters` internally, so that any `add_filter` by the coder will modify their outputs. `apply_filters` ain't creating nothing.

Comment: For better or worse, many hooks in WordPress are named the same as a function. But generally speaking, if you _want something_, call the function, and if you want to _change something_ for everyone (including yourself) add a filter, and if you want to _do something_ then add an action.